# SQL Query Advance Salary counting with carry forward of monthly balance

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am displaying total balance with carry forward of all months by selecting month
if i have selected Month March and following

```
emp_id ==== bal_amt ==== advance_sal ==== date ==== basic_salary
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1           48000           2000       2019-01-10     50000
 1           46000           2000       2019-01-11     50000
 2           78000           2000       2019-01-11     80000
 2           75000           3000       2019-01-11     80000
 1           49000           1000       2019-02-10     50000
 2           74000           6000       2019-02-11     80000
```

if i select month February then i want last balance amount of each id to be selected with total balance amount which is less than February

please see the selected row below

```
emp_id ==== bal_amt ==== advance_sal ==== date ==== basic_salary
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1           48000           2000       2019-01-10     50000
 1           46000           2000       2019-01-11     50000 -- select
 2           78000           2000       2019-01-11     80000
 2           75000           3000       2019-01-11     80000 -- select
 1           49000           1000       2019-02-10     50000 -- select
 2           74000           6000       2019-02-11     80000 -- select
```

```
SELECT *
FROM advance_sal x JOIN
  (SELECT empp_id, max(id)
   FROM advance_sal
   WHERE empp_id = 1
     AND MONTH(`ad_date`)<="2"
     AND YEAR(`ad_date`)<="2019" group_by empp_id) y ON y.empp_id = x.empp_id
AND y.id = x.id
ORDER BY x.id
```

So total result would be

```
emp_id ==== bal_amt ==== advance_sal ==== date ==== basic_salary
----------------------------------------------------------------
 1           46000           2000       2019-01-11     50000
 2           75000           3000       2019-01-11     80000
 1           49000           1000       2019-02-10     50000
 2           74000           6000       2019-02-11     80000

emp_id ==== total_bal_amount less than February
----------------------------------------------------------------
 1           95000         
 2           149000
```

any help to write sql query

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: sorry for late reply. request you to elaborate your question i actually didn't get I am newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need below query. I'm not just sure though how you decide which last balance you need from multiple same date as your date doesn't have a timestamp.

```
SELECT *, SUM(bal_amt) over(partition by emp_id) fROM (
SELECT emp_id, bal_amt, advance_sal, date, basic_salary, RN = Row_number() over(partition by emp_id order by date desc)
FROM advance_sal where  
     MONTH(`ad_date`)<="2"
     AND YEAR(`ad_date`)<="2019" ) a where RN = 1
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This query is giving error to check in manual near partition can you please tell me exact query to fetch data

Comment: I am not familiar with partition queries my MYSQL version is 5.6.36 i think it don't run in this version